# Error in PL/SQL function

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to create a function that divides min by 60, but when I compile, I received the error:
Compilation failed,line 8 (14:53:49) PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" when expecting one of the following: (

Here's the code:

```
create or replace function "HORAS"
(min in NUMBER)
return NUMBER
is
hr NUMBER;

begin
    hr:= (min) /(60);
  return hr;
end;​
```

Answer (score 2):

`MIN` is a [built-in aggregate/analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions100.htm#sthref1252), so the compiler is expecting it to be followed by arguments, hence the message saying it's expecting `(`.

Just change the argument name; you also don't really need to define an intermediate variable:

```
create or replace function HORAS (p_min in NUMBER)
return NUMBER
is
begin
  return p_min / 60;
end;
/

select horas(345) from dual;

HORAS(345)
----------
      5.75
```